# Dateformatter date string return nil

Tags: ios, swift, date

When I use DatePicker to set date

It said it was nil

Despite I checked the date string format is correct

And dateFormat is set to format that I want.

Here's code

```
class DatePickerViewController: UIViewController {

var originDate: String!{ 
        didSet{
            //print("\(originDate)") is like "2019/07/12"
            selectedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: originDate)
           //print("\(selectedDate)") is nil
            datePicker.setDate(selectedDate, animated: true)
        }
 }

var selectedDate: Date!
var dateString: String = "yyyy/MM/dd"
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateString

}
```

The ShowPickerViewController call DatePickerViewController

```
class ShowPickerViewController:UIViewcontroller {

   @IBAction func showDatePicker(_ sender: Any) {

   let vc = DatePickerViewController()

   vc.originDate = sender.text // "2019/07/12"

   present(vc, animated: true)

   }

}
```

Comment: Most likely `viewDidLoad` is called after you set `originDate`.

Comment: Initialize the date format with a closure & use data format YYYY/MM/dd

Comment: @Friend Do not use `YYYY`, use `yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the date formatter with a closure

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
   return formatter
}()
```

and delete the line in `viewDidLoad`